# R remove duplicate spatial points according an attribute

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

In R I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame whit duplicated point (coordinates and attributes), I would like to remove all point with same data ...

I have find in the `sp` package the `remove.duplicates()` function but it seems to remove only on location ...  Is there another way?

thank you

E.

Comment: Can you give a toy example for which `unique()` does not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
library(sp)
pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4)))
pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data=data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)))

## All points
pts

## No spatial duplicates
remove.duplicates(pts)

## No duplicates in attributes
pts[which(!duplicated(pts$id)), ]

## Combination
pts[which(!duplicated(as.data.frame(pts))), ]
```